# SignalR hub connection does not work in Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, signalr

I'm trying to connect using the following code:

```cs
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol()
    .WithUrl(myUrl, options =>
    {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = myAccessTokenProvider;
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();
    
await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
```

When this code is executed in Xamarin Forms iOS, I get the below exception:

> [0:] A suitable constructor for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.UnnamedOptionsManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionOptions]'
> could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are
> registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

I tried disabling linking which seemed to address the above issue, but I ended up getting another one instead (thrown by the `StartAsync` call):

> Method not found:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiationResponse
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiateProtocol.ParseResponse(System.ReadOnlySpan`1)

How do I address this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20805#issuecomment-791440473

Answer (score 0):

Either disable Xaml HotReload, or use VS 2019, or wait for a fix..

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Bug-in-Visual-studio-2022--Xamarin--Si/1528510